# "form_with cannot find the Post model"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model, routes, controller

I am trying to create the form on my "new" page. I am using form_with. I have already checked my routes, controllers and views, but I have not yet identified the problem.

The error that is returning is:

```
NameError in Pages # new
undefined local variable or method `post 'for # <# <Class: 0x00007f5640e1f440>: 0x00007f5640e1c060>
Did you mean? @post
Extracted source (around line # 5):

    <% = form_with (model: post, location: true) do | form | %>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <% = form.label: title%>
```

Below is my form using form_with:

```
<h1> CREATE NEW ARTICLE </h1>
<% = form_with (model: post, location: true) do | form | %>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <% = form.label: title%>
    <% = form.text_field: title, class: 'form-control'%>
  </div>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <% = form.label: author%>
    <% = form.text_field: author, class: 'form-control'%>
  </div>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <% = form.label: body%>
    <% = form.text_area: body, class: 'form-control', rows: 10%>
  </div>
    <% = form.submit class: 'btn btn-primary', data: {disable_with: 'Creating ..'}%>
<% end%>
```

this is my controller:

```
class PagesController <ApplicationController
def articles
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def show
   @post = Post.find (params [: id])
  end

  def create
    @post = @ Post.new (post_params)
    @ post.save
    redirect_to article_path (@post)
   end
 private

  def post_params
    params.require (: post) .permit (: title,: author,: body)
  end
end
```

Now here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'pages # index'
get 'articles', to: 'pages # articles'
 get 'articles / new', to: 'pages # new'
 get 'articles /: id', to: 'pages # show', as: 'article'
 post 'articles', to: 'pages # create'
end
```

Comment: Do you actually have a post model?

Comment: Yes.including I can create post on the console without problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<% = form_with(model: post, location: true) do | form | %>
.....
<% end %>
```

with

```
<% = form_with(model: post, local: true) do | form | %>
....
<% end %>
```

and `new.html.erb` should contains

```
<%= render 'form', post: @post` %>
```

And update your controller with `posts_controller.rb`

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_post, only: [:show]

 def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def show
   
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
   end
 
private
 def find_post
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :author, :body)
  end
end
```

`Routes` should be as

```
get 'posts', to: 'posts#index'
get 'posts/new', to: 'posts#new'
get 'posts/:id', to: 'posts#show'
post 'posts', to: 'posts#create'
```

or simply as

```
resources :posts, only: [:index, :new, :show, :create]
```

Comment: I did it ( `<%= form_with(model: post, local: true) do |form| %>`)  but the error appears: `undefined method `posts_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000561416b23f60>:0x00005614177f2b10>`

Comment: @Lucas Araujo with ```<%= form_with(model: post, local: true) do |form| %>)``` rails will provide the ```posts_path url helper``` but in your ```routes``` it is not defined. I have updated the ```controller``` as well as ```routes```.  Please see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a lot of whitespace issues going on in your code snippets, but I think that might be a side effect of however you've copied the code rather than any deliberate cause.

The error you're seeing is because the `form_with` method doesn't know what `post` is. In your controller, you set up `@post` in your `new` method, which means that `new.html.erb` will be able to see the instance variable `@post`, but it won't know what `post` (without the `@`) is.

So if the form is in `new.html.erb`, you'd need to use `@post` in place of `post` here.

That said, common Rails behaviour is to have the form in its own partial `_form.html.erb`. That might be the case here (you don't specify the file names of your views). In that case, you can tell the partial to use **local variables** rather than the **instance variable** that the main template file uses.

To do that, you need to map an instance variable to a local one in the `render` call to your form, for example:

```
# in new.html.erb
<%= render 'form', post: @post` %>
```

This is saying 'take the object that I can see as `@post`, and make it available as the `post` local variable within the form template'.

Comment: I created a partial _form.html.erb, put all my code in the form and my new.html.erb page now only has the <% = render 'form', post: @post%>